# google integration with android studio app

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, google-authentication

While setting the app to authentication with google account, the data is showing warning.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_CODE) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> signInTask = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);

        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount signInAcc = signInTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Connected google", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This warning is mentioned:

```
 error: ';' expected
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent  data) {
```

And the data is showing red warning. How can I avoid this error?

Comment: Can you show more context? What is before this snippet?

Comment: At which line of code are you getting that error?